# Star Schema from multiple source tables

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse, denormalization, star-schema, fact-table

I am struggling in figuring out how to create a star schema from multiple source tables.  I work at a trading firm so the data is related to user trading activity.  The issue I am having is that our datasets do not have primary ids for every field that could be a dimension. Instead, we usually relate our data together using the combination of date and account number.  Here is an example of 3 source tables...

[image]

I would like to turn this into a star schema, something that looks like ...

[image]

Is my only option to denormalize my source tables into one wide table (joining trades to position on account number and date, and joining the users table on account number), create keys for each dimension, then re normalizing it into the star schema? Are star schema's ever built from multiple source tables?

Answer (score 1):

Star schemas are almost always created from multiple source tables.

The normal process is:

1. Populate your dimension tables
2. Create a temporary/virtual fact record using your source data
3. Using this fact record, look up the relevant dimension keys
4. Write the actual fact record to your target fact table

Comment: would this virtual fact record (step 2) be created by joining the raw source tables to get a complete "transaction" in one row? I am thinking this is the only way dimensions know about each other (that is if they are in the same row/record).

Comment: Yes - it will contain all the fact information necessary to lookup the relevant dims and then populate the fact table

Answer (score 1):

Data-warehousing is about query speed.  The data-warehouse should not be concerned with data integrity.  IT SHOULD NOT CLEAN OR CORRECT BAD DATA.  It only needs to gather all the data together into a single record to present to the model for analysis.  Denormalizing the data is how this is done.

In a star schema, dimensions do not know about each other and have no relationships with other dimensions.  In a snowflake, dimensions are related to other dimensions.  That is the primary difference between star and snowflake.

All the metadata options for events are rolled up into dimensions and used for slicing/filtering.  All the measurable/calculation data for an event are in the event fact, along with a reference to the dimension(s) containing the relevant metadata.  The Metadata/Dimension is reused across multiple fact records.

Based on the limited example you've provided, I'd suggest you research degenerate dimensions and junk dimensions.  Your Trade and Position data may need to be turned into a fact and a dimension (degenerate), and some of your flag attributes may be best placed into a junk dimension.

You should also make sure your dimension keys are clear.  You should not have multiple paths to a dimension (accountnumber: trade -> position -> user & trade -> user ) as that will cause inconsistent results when querying depending on which relationship you traverse.